# Перемещение ячейки UITableViewCell Drag'n'Drop-ом по UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-n-drop, swift4

Задача состоит в том, что бы создать Drag'n'Drop-систему, позволяющую "схватить" долгим нажатием ячейку в `UITableView` таким образом, что бы в это же время можно было нажимать на другие ячейки и жестом возвращаться на предыдущий `UIViewController`, осуществляя навигацию по древу файлов. Такая система реализована в MacOS в файловом менеджере Finder.

Предпринятые попытки

**Попытка #1**

При удержании `UITableViewCell` более 0.5 секунд (Что отслеживается при помощи `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, наложенного на саму `UITableViewCell`,) появляется тень, вычисляются абсолютные координаты ячейки, и она переносится в `window`, после чего, при помощи методов `touchesMoved` осуществляется её передвижение путём изменения её `transform`-свойств.

Проблема в том, что при перемещении `UITableViewCell` в `window`, все текущие `UITouch`, принадлежащие ей, отменяются. Способа обойти эту проблему на просторах интернета я найти не смог.

**Попытка #2**

Отслеживать нажатия внутри `UINavigationController`. Я действовал по логике, что нажатия внутри него не будут сбрасываться, и если сильно заморочиться, то можно отследить сначала длинное нажатие на ячейке, а после сдвиг этого нажатия.

Проблема оказалась такова: События нажатия просто не "доходят" до `UINavigationController` из-за очень большого обилия элементов на нём.

**Надеюсь на Вашу помощь!**

Comment: Пальцы пользователей вы бы пожалели. Это ж какое мучение будет так работать! (Надеюсь, у вас ничего не получится.)

Comment: @sanmai, Ну зачем же так демотивировать, авось получится что-то хорошее :) Такое, например, в приложении Dropbox реализовано, пользоваться очень даже удобно